# PHP segmentation fault with Couchbase SDK

Tags: php, couchbase

I just tried to install the PHP SDK on my Ubuntu 14.04.
I started with the C SDK, then isntalled the PHP SDK with `pecl`. 
Everything works fine, i got no errors, a couchbase.so is installed in /usr/lib/php55/…

But when i add a 
`extension=couchbase.so` to my php.ini everything broke, i can't display any php page.

I checked the logs and see:

`[Wed Jan 20 11:36:39.872396 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4265] AH00052: child pid 4298 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`
Looks bad uh ?

Any tips to make this works?

Comment: Make sure the library version is compatible with your php version. Another option is the library has errors and as a result, you see the segmentation fault. I need more details of that segmentation fault. Have you tried in another SO?

Comment: I installed the C SDK with the `perl couchbase-csdk-setup` command. I ask me if i'm runnig 64bits trusty which i do...Maybe i should recompile the stuff the hard way ?

Comment: Yes, that can be one reason

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned this to the project maintainer this morning and his hypothesis is that PHP may have had a change in 5.5 that has lead to the breakage as he's seen this sort of thing in the past.  Perhaps you can try an older version or get more info per the comment on backtraces above.